# 'Disable' An Application

Tags: ubuntu

I have the MintUpdate update manager on my Ubuntu 20.04 and I really like it. But the default software manager keeps popping up with updates. How do you make it stop?

Comment: Generally Linux updates to stable versions are for security reasons, and you'll probably want to apply them if you value your data.  You may choose not to do a major version update from 20.04 to 20.10, though.  Your question is a little short on details, so it's hard to say without more information on what exactly the updates are.

Comment: Does this help: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/07/how-to-stop-installing-updates.html

Comment: @bk2204 Sometimes I don't want to do kernel updates

Comment: @ajgringo619 No. It is the update-manager or the gnome software updater that does the updates without my say-so and I want it to stop.